# How to speed up for loop in python using Cython

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, cython, beagleboneblack

I am trying to make a sensor using Beaglebone Black(BBB) and Python. I need to get as much data as possible per second from a sensor. The code bellow allows me to collect about 100,000 data points per second.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO_GPIO as GPIO
import time 

GPIO.setup("P8_13", GPIO.IN)

def get_data(n):
    my_list = []
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append(GPIO.input("P8_13"))
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print "Time: {}".format(end-time)
    return my_list

n = 100000
get_data(n)
```

If n = 1,000,000, it takes around 10 seconds to populate my_list which is the same rate when n = 100,000 and time = 1s.

I decided to try Cython to get better results. I've heard it can significantly speed up python code. I followed the basic Cython tutorial: created data.pyx file with the python code above, then created a setup.py and, finally, built the Cython file.

Unfortunately, that did not help me at all. So, I am wondering if I am using Cython inappropriately or in this case, when there are  no "heavy math computations", Cython cannot help too much. Any suggestions on how to speed up my code are highly appreciated!

Comment: using recursion instead of a for loop, if you do it well enough you can have it go down to O(logn) where as a for is O(n) and a log grows slower then a constant

Comment: this is also a good resource https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Comment: @jgr208 Thank you for your suggestions. I will read the article you provided.

Comment: In your cython implementation, did you change `my_list` to an array? As I understand it, if the content of your loop involves only operations on C types, then the loop will be converted to C and run relatively fast; if there are still python types in there (e.g. appending to a python `list`) then I think you're missing the benefits of cython

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the point. I did not change my_list to an array. My understanding is that when I build the data.pyx, cython takes care of all required conversions but I've have used cython before so I can be wrong.

Comment: It might also be that simply reading the input pin is taking a nontrivial amount of time; to test that hypothesis you could omit the list appending step in the loop (but keep the pin reading step) and see how long just the loop by itself takes. That will tell you an (unreachable) lower bound; if it's very close to what you're getting now, however, then you know it won't be useful to try to speed it up, as it's a physical limitation of how long it takes to read the pin input

Comment: If you tried the above suggestion and it looks like there's room for improvement, then I would suggest annotating your pyx file, to let you know what's happening in the conversion: you can do that in the terminal with `cython -a <filename>.pyx` that'll produce an HTML output file telling you where the slow regions are (they show up in yellow). http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types

Comment: @Ryan Thank you very much for your help. I will definitely check your hypothesis about physical limitations. I really like that idea. I'll keep you updated. Also, thanks for the link!

Comment: @Ryan Just finished testing. The difference between looping with list appending and without is around 0.1 second. Sounds not too promising. On your opinion, if this "for loop" will be written, for example, in C++, will I see the difference?  Thank you.

Comment: I would interpret that as meaning that no matter what language you implement in, you'll be limited to how fast the device can read the input pin. It might be worth it to look into ways to reduce the number of times through the loop, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by adding a static type declaration:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO_GPIO as GPIO
import time 

GPIO.setup("P8_13", GPIO.IN)

def get_data(int n):  # declared as an int
    my_list = []
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append(GPIO.input("P8_13"))
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print "Time: {}".format(end-time)
    return my_list

n = 100000
get_data(n)
```

This allows the loop itself to be converted into a pure C loop, with the disadvantage that `n` is no longer arbitrary precision (so if you try to pass a value larger than ~2 billion, you'll get undefined behavior).  This issue can be mitigated by changing `int` to `unsigned long long`, which allows values up to 2**64 - 1, or around 18 quintillion.  The `unsigned` quantifier means you won't be able to pass a negative value.

You'll get a much more substantial speed boost if you can eliminate the list.  Try replacing it with an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).  Cython can [work more efficiently with arrays than with lists](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/array.html#array-array).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Declaring n as int gave an insignificant speed improvement. Will try to replace the list with an array.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your same code, but with a different build of Adafruit_BBIO,
the one million count take only about 3 seconds to run on my rev C board.

I thought that the main change in the board from Rev B to Rev C was the fact that the eMMC was increased from 2GB to 4GB.

If you go and get the current Adafruit_BBIO, all you have to change in your above code is the first import statement, it should be `Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO`

What have you tried out next?

Ron

Comment: I  burned my BBB  out sometime ago and  decided to try Micro Python and I am happy with it so far. The only thing that slightly improved the sampling rate using BBB was to use list comprehension instead of regular "for" loop.